# How can I visit a package's homepage via the pip command?

Tags: python, package-management, pip

Being new to both Python and particularly the `pip` package manager, I'm wondering if `pip` has an internal command for quickly opening a package's home page on the web.

If not possible by default, is there any available solution(s) for extending `pip` with this functionality (e.g. `pip homepage django-boss`)?

For comparison, I'm looking for something equivalent to [Homebrew's](https://brew.sh/):

`brew home somepackage`, which opens `somepackage`'s home page in your default web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` doesn't provide the functionality you require.

The [pypi-tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypi-tools/0.0.2) package may serve as a base for a solution. It installs the `pypi` command which allows to search for packages in *PyPI* or show the information for a specific package:

```
$ pypi -s django-boss
 name:                django-boss
 summary:             Django management commands, revisited.
 version:             0.6.3
 author:              Zachary Voase
 author_email:        zacharyvoase@me.com
 classifiers:         
 home_page:           http://github.com/zacharyvoase/django-boss
 package_url:         http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-boss
 release_url:         http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-boss/0.6.3
 docs_url:
```

By perusing the package's source you should be able to integrate the module into a script of yours that gets the package's url and then invokes a browser with it.